# Why when launching Chrome and loading html file to chrome it's taking so much time to load it?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the line in the constructor :

```
Process.Start("chrome.exe", 
              ScrambledHtmlFilePath);
```

ScrambledHtmlFilePath is the html file on my hard disk.
If i just surf regular with Chrome to cnn.com for example the website is loading very fast.

But once i load the html file from the hard disk fro example of cnn after downloaded the html and saved it with WebClient then its taking a veryl ong time untill the file is loaded with Chrome.

I mean the Process start Chrome very fast in a second but then i see this sign of loading the site and its taking like 15-20 seconds untill the site start to load.

Comment: If you do `Process.Start("chrome.exe", "http://www.cnn.com");`, is it also slow?

Comment: keyboardP no it's very fast when using it as you did. But the only thing i changed in the html file on my hard disk was some text inside all tags and all other content left the same as it was.

Comment: Have you tried to look at time consumed by loading various page elements in the Network tab in Chrome's Developer Tools (Chrome's Settings)? Open Chrome manually and load page saved locally and see where's the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because the page you are trying to load has its html part in other file and other elements belonging to same page are in a folder,not to mention designer webpages and sites have hundreds and thousands of elements in them.From elements i mean separate stylesheets,separate script files,graphics such as images including site banner and others etc.Assigning hundreds of elements to correct places obviously takes some time.
               My opinion would be to first change the following setting in Chrome(To change them type 'chrome://flags' (without quotes) and press Enter button this will bring you to internal settings page of Chrome).Once you have settings page opened locate following setting **Save Page as MHTML** and **Enable** it,then try to download the page again.Then use this code

```
Process.Start("Chrome.exe","Path to MHTML file");
```

**MHTML** is one of the formats used by Internet Explorer.In MHTML the saved paged is archived as MHTML which includes everything in it,its one separate files that holds webpage and nothing else.
I am not sure if this is works but it should lessen the page load time in Chrome.